# How to change theme in documentation.js?

Tags: npm, themes, node-modules, jsdoc3, documentationjs

I would like to use [this theme](https://github.com/documentationjs/documentation-theme-light) for my documentation.

I use documentationjs. I tried a lot of things but I have no idea how to use it, can somebody help?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried [this theme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentation-devseed-theme) and it worked just fine

```
npm install --save-dev documentation-devseed-theme
documentation build -f html -o docs --theme node_modules/documentation-devseed-theme src/**
```